# Trunk only one VLAN to an attached switch.

Tags: switch, vlan

I have a netgear GSM7324 and a managed Cisco switch. I need to connect the Cisco switch to the netgear. The Cisco switch will only need to have vlan 3 on it. Do I still need to set up a trunk port to connect the Cisco and Netgear or would it just set it for switch port mode access and switch access vlan 3 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create the vlan on both sides and use a tagged trunk port for this. It might sound overkill, but imagine the warm fuzzy feeling you'll get inside the day you need to add another VLAN to the switches.

Edit: It's easy on Cisco switches to limit which VLANS who can travel across the trunk port:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description Trunkport to Netgear switch
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 3
 switchport mode trunk
 speed 1000
 duplex full
end
```

Comment: +1 for probably needing more VLANS in the future

Comment: the vlan is already created on both sides. On both interfaces do I enter the following command: switch port trunk ?

Comment: On Cisco IOS the command is `switchport **mode** trunk`. What works on netGear is anybody's guess.

Comment: You could also use "switchport trunk allowed-vlan" to make sure that only certain VLAN's are accepted on the trunk link.

Answer (score 2):

On Cisco equipment, VLAN 1 is always a member of any trunk - you cannot exclude it.

Either make sure you know the implications, or don't use VLAN 1.

Before someone thinks I misread his question - this means that ANY trunk with one defined VLAN will in actual fact contain **two** - the defined VLAN and VLAN 1.

Comment: yeah Im fine with the native vlan getting to it, I just need to make sure vlan 3 gets from one switch to the other.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need one vlan the easiest and cleanest way is to set the port to access.

**EDIT:** Ok, so some questions:

- Do netgear support perVLAN spanning tree on its trunk ports?
- Do netgear support CDP or VTP?
- what kind of loop detection netgear uses?

If one just connect these two switches in their basement all is fine.

I saw huge problems connecting Huawei and Cisco switches in an enterprise network.
However Huawei is not the cheapest SOHO gear.

Comment: Easiest, yes.. but further down the road if you ever want to add more vlans it's not easy at all.

Comment: If you mix cisco switches with dumb switches like netgear do not let their trunk ports together or chaos will emerge. (Believe me that kind of setup asks for trouble.)

Comment: the netgear is a layer 3 switch

Comment: @cstamas: Also incorrect. Any managed layer2 switch can operate fine with Cisco equipment. VLAN is VLAN.

Comment: @pauska it all depends on if you want to create a network or a mess. Read my update.

Comment: @cstamas: No, you are still incorrect. You can't base your 1 bad experience with Huawei gear with every other brand in the world. We have Cisco switches talking VLAN and STP to Cisco, HP, Linksys and Netgear switches here without problems.

Comment: @pauska you did not answered my question.